# Assign internal static IP addresses to 2 pods of same statefulsets GKE GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-vpc

I have two pods of the same statefulset in GKE GCP. They are assigned IP addresses from a secondary ip address range, I want them to expose the using 2 individual static ip addresses from primary ip address range of VPC. How can I do that ? Please note using cluster_ipv4_cidr_block in ip_allocation_policy of VPC native cluster is not an option since the size of subnet of primary ip address is smaller than required. What other ways I can achieve this ? Note- I do not want to load balance traffic, one pod will be the active node and the other is passive.

Comment: Are you trying to expose these outside the cluster?  And do they only need to be accessed from other apps running on the same VPC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GKE internal load balancer with annotations solves this.